When listing chromeos devices and querying based on last_user_activity, why don't the activeTimeRanges seem to make sense with my query?
I'm trying to programmatically get the minutes of use time per ChromeOS device that we manage, daily. So I'm using the directory api's endpoint for getting all our ChromeOS devices, which includes some activeTimeRanges that have the use time I'm looking for. I'm using the query parameter to only list devices used within the last day, since I'm using this info daily.
But when I used last_user_activity:2024-10-31.., which should give me computers that were last used by users either on 2024-10-31 or later, I got results that have their latest activeTimeRange as 2024-10-30. The returned json doesn't have a field for last_user_activity, so what's it based off of if not activeTimeRange? Why is this result showing up, if according to the activeTimeRange's it wasn't used on the 31st or later? And then a few hours later, I did get an activeTimeRange for that computer that was for today. Are the activeTimeRange's only updated at the end of the user's session or something, while the last_user_activity is more current?
Things I've done to try figuring it out: I've been looking at the docs for the query part of the request but they don't say much about last_user_activity, and I can't find much about the activeTimeRange either. I thought at first maybe some timezone schenanigans were to blame with the java libraries google provides, but debugging into it I don't think that's true, as setting my default timezone to UTC didn't change anything.
